# Hide all video divs when one is selected

Tags: javascript, jquery, hide, swap

I'm a newbie with Javascript and having a hard time figuring out the correct code for this function.

I have multiple `div`s.  Each `div` has 2 child `div`s that swap when clicked.

For instance,  the first `div` is a styled image with a rollover effect.  When the image is clicked, it swaps with a `<video>`.

However, I'm trying to add some functionality to the this... If I click on another image to play the `<video>`, I want the other `video`s to stop and swap back to the original image `div`s.

Here's the code I'm testing with.

```js
function SwapDivsWithClick(div1, div2) {
  d1 = document.getElementById(div1);
  d2 = document.getElementById(div2);
  if (d2.style.display == "none") {
    d1.style.display = "none";
    d2.style.display = "block";
  } else {
    d1.style.display = "block";
    d2.style.display = "none";
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="project1Img" class="showDiv" style="display:block; border:2px dashed red; padding:25px;">
  <p style="margin:0; color:red;">
    <a href="javascript:SwapDivsWithClick('project1Img','project1Vid')">Img1</a>
  </p>
</div>
<div id="project1Vid" class="hideDiv" style="display:none; border:2px dotted blue; padding:25px;">
  <video>video content</video>
</div>

<div id="project2Img" class="showDiv" style="display:block; border:2px dashed red; padding:25px;">
  <p style="margin:0; color:red;">
    <a href="javascript:SwapDivsWithClick('project2Img','project2Vid')">Img2</a>
  </p>
</div>
<div id="project2Vid" class="hideDiv" style="display:none; border:2px dotted blue; padding:25px;">
  <video>video content</video>
</div>

<div id="project3Img" class="showDiv" style="display:block; border:2px dashed red; padding:25px;">
  <p style="margin:0; color:red;">
    <a href="javascript:SwapDivsWithClick('project3Img','project3Vid')">Img3</a>
  </p>
</div>

<div id="project3Vid" class="hideDiv" style="display:none; border:2px dotted blue; padding:25px;">
  <video>video content</video>
</div>
```

The problem I'm trying to solve is that when you click a second link, then the other two revert back to the original `div1`.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `document.getElementsByClassName('showDiv')` and loop through them (skipping to the next iteration of the loop if the element id matches the `div1` argument), and set `style.display='block'` on all of them. This will show all the images except the one with the id of `div1`.

Then use `document.getElementsByClassName('hideDiv')` and loop through them (again, skipping to the next one if the element id matches `div2`), and set `style.display='none'`. This will hide all the videos except the id of `div2`.

This will reset all the `div`s in your list (regardless of how many there are) to their default state, and then you can hide `div1` and show `div2`, and you're done.

This replacement function will do exactly what you want:

```
function SwapDivsWithClick(div1, div2) {
  var d = document.getElementsByClassName('showDiv');
  for (i = 0; i < d.length; ++i) {
    d[i].style.display = (d[i].id == div1) ? 'none' : 'block';
  }
  d = document.getElementsByClassName('hideDiv');
  for (i = 0; i < d.length; ++i) {
    d[i].style.display = (d[i].id == div2) ? 'block' : 'none';
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi, I see you're new to the community. If you wouldn't mind, when you see an answer that works for you, there's a checkmark thing by the vote count where you can mark your question as answered.

Answer (score 0):

Are you open to using jQuery or another DOM manipulation library?  You can write something to solve this problem relatively easily if the weight of the file isn't a problem.  In any case, if you use native JS, you might want to focus your energy on the ability to loop thru DOM elements.

Here is an easy version in jQuery

```js
$('.toggler').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  var thisProjectVideo = $(this).parents('.projectImg').siblings('.projectVid');
  var thisProjectImg = $(this).parents('.projectImg');
  var allProjectVids = $('.projectVid');
  var allprojectImgs = $('.projectImg');

  allprojectImgs.removeClass('displayNone');  
  thisProjectImg.addClass('displayNone');
  allProjectVids.addClass('displayNone');
  thisProjectVideo.removeClass('displayNone');

})
```

```css
.displayNone {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="videoContainer">
  <div id="project1Img" class="projectImg showDiv" style="border:2px dashed red; padding:25px;">
    <p style="margin:0; color:red;">
      <a class="toggler">Img1</a>
    </p>
  </div>
  <div id="project1Vid" class="projectVid hideDiv displayNone" style="border:2px dotted blue; padding:25px;">
    <video>video content</video>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="videoContainer">
  <div id="project2Img" class="projectImg showDiv" style="border:2px dashed red; padding:25px;">
    <p style="margin:0; color:red;">
      <a class="toggler">Img2</a>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div id="project2Vid" class="projectVid hideDiv displayNone" style="border:2px dotted blue; padding:25px;">
    <video>video content</video>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="videoContainer">
  <div id="project3Img" class="projectImg showDiv" style="border:2px dashed red; padding:25px;">
    <p style="margin:0; color:red;">
      <a class="toggler">Img3</a>
    </p>
  </div>

  <div id="project3Vid" class="projectVid hideDiv displayNone" style="border:2px dotted blue; padding:25px;">
    <video>video content</video>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Hmm, that isn't quite working for me... clicking on Img1 hides Img2. In any case, the solution without jquery is straightforward and quite short.

Comment: Forgot to add -- I'm not a jquery wizard, so I wouldn't mind seeing the code above corrected so that I can understand it better.

Comment: I thought the goal was that a user clicks on Img1 and Img2 and Img3 hide?  This is intended functionality.  I did a cross browser check and there are no errors in the code, maybe I misunderstood the question?

Comment: I can redo the code if you can explain desired functionality in further detail (but if the native answer is good for you, then no need)

Comment: I wrote the native answer, but I'd like to see the jquery solution. No, clicking on any Img hides it and shows the video container, and shows the Img containers in all the other places. The requester wants it to work like a radio button, where the "on" state is the empty video container, and the "off" state is Img1, Img2, or Img3, and only one can be "on" at a time.

Comment: Ok, I just updated the code snippet in my answer to reflect this.   Hopefully that's closer to the intended functionality.